# How to put a password when opening an Excel file using Python?

Tags: python, openpyxl, password-protection

```
from openpyxl.workbook.protection import WorkbookProtection
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook(path, keep_vba=True)

wb.security = WorkbookProtection()
wb.security.workbookPassword = 'test_password'
wb.security.lockStructure = True

ws = wb.active
# some code 
wb.save(filename=path)
```

I tried to use the code above to password-protect an Excel file. There is no error but there is also no password prompt.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide more details. What do you mean by no password request?

Comment: I want to set a password when export an excel, so than other user may need a password to access the workbook

Comment: @EmrahDiril No =L=

Comment: You want to put a password when *opening* an Excel file? Because [openpyxl]'s `WorkbookProtection` only works for preventing modifying sheets, etc.

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes,as you know, any other way can do that? since the content is kind of confidential

Comment: I can protect the sheets right now, maybe just hidden content if the password not been enter, however i don't know how to check the password have been enter or not

Comment: I don't think there's a way for `openpyxl` to put a password on opening the file. It only offers [basic protection](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html): "*“Worksheet or workbook element protection should not be confused with file security. It is meant to make your workbook safe from unintentional modification...*". You'll have to consider alternative solutions, such as zipping-up the excel file then password-protecting that zip file, or converting the excel to a PDF then password-protecting the PDF.

Comment: Why don't you make python ask for a password and then simply open the file if it is correct?

Comment: Because I can only send excel to other pepole and they don't use python...

Comment: @GinoMempin After google, zip with password is a easy way. But...  maybe other library/module that i don't know can handle the encrypt?
Thank you for your suggestion !!!!!!!!

Comment: There's a *very* limited number of Python libraries that can handle Excel files: openpyxl, xlsxwriter, xlwings. None of them though offers the function that you need. I would use a different way for serving the data, something that has password protection support.